# Need to create subdomain on WordPress website

Tags: wordpress, subdomain

My website: `http://www.igeniee.com/company`

After signup, I need to create a subdomain Example: xyz/igeniee.com
I am using the purchased theme.

Can any one help, how may I create this?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand when user signup,  you need to create a sub domain as companyname.igeniee.com ? Note, the xyz/igeniee.com is not a valid sub domain.

To do that, you must have created A record as follows.

```
A Record | * |  11.22.33.44
```

Also, you must have server alias as follows(apache) in your web server virtual host configuration.

ServerAlias *.igeniee.com

I hope, this link will help you for virtual host configuration. https://askubuntu.com/questions/881905/how-to-configure-apache-to-multiple-subdomains